# DBGrid - OnCellClick & OnDblClick, return a form/TBMemo containing cell/column value/s

Tags: mysql, delphi, dbgrid, tdbgrid

I'm using the following code added to my DBGrid - OnCellClick event

```
procedure TForm2.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
if dbmodule.comenziDataSet.Active then
  begin
    if not Assigned(dbgridCelulaForm) then
    begin
      dbgridCelulaForm := TdbgridCelulaForm.Create(Self);
      dbgridCelulaForm.DBMemoCelula.DataSource := dbmodule.comenziSource; 
    end;

    dbgridCelulaForm.Visible := False;
    dbgridCelulaForm.Visible := True;
    dbgridCelulaForm.DBMemoCelula.DataField := Column.FieldName;
    dbgridCelulaForm.Caption := Format('%s / randul: %d',[Column.FieldName, DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.RecNo]);
  end;
end;
```

dbgridCelulaForm = name of the form containing the `TDBMemo`
DBMemoCelula = name of the `TDBMemo`
dbmodule.comenziDataSet = comenziDataSet is the name of the `DataSet` and dbmodule is the name of a `data module` (unit, like forms) - the `DataSet` is on the `data module`, so, dbmodule.comenziDataSet
dbmodule.comenziSource = same as data set, a DataSource on a data module, the source is named comenziSource

Ok so what this code does:

Once I click a cell on my `DBGrid` it pops up a `form` (named dbgridCelulaForm) which contains a `TBMemo` (named DBMemoCelula) and it shows me the information contained in that cell (like, a Customer Name for example, or whatever the cell is holding, in my db)

This is fine, my problem is I can't select rows now in `DBGrid`, well, I can but once I do the 1st place I click (a cell, any) on the particular row I want to select with my mouse, then cell activates and the `form` pops up.

Is it possible to use this code in `DBGrid` - `OnDblClick` event instead of the `OnCellClick` ?
Meaning once i double click a row / cell the `form` should pop up and show me the info, but double click - not single click.

That way, I can still select the row and still view the info in the cell if I need to.

Or any other way/place to use/receive this functionality.
Any thoughts?

I can post a quick video of everything if my explanation is ambiguous and you think that would help, just tell me in the comment / answer.

Also, I'm using RAD Studio 10 Seattle and dbexpress components for the database - if that helps.

Thanks!

Comment: No ambiguity at all... The way I implemented similar functionality is through the edit button of the grid columns - fires an OnEditButtonClick event on the grid. Set the button style to cbsEllipsis so that it is evident that a dialog pops when it is clicked. Can also be triggered with Alt+Down.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I'm already using OnEditButtonClick for something else, so can't use that. Martyn's answer does help, same for your SelectedField comment, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code shows how to access the Column and Row coordinates of a dbl-clicked cell of a TDBGrid, and the string value of the cell contents.

As written, it displays the cell's Column and Row number + string contents on the form's caption.  Up to you what you actually do with these values.

It work because the dataset cursor on the dataset connected to the DBGrid is moved to the dataset row corresponding to the cell where the mouse pointer is.

```
type
 TMyDBGrid = class(TDBGrid);

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ARow,
  ACol : Integer;
  Pt : TPoint;
  CellValue : String;
begin
  //  First, get the mouse pointer coordinates
  Pt.X := Mouse.CursorPos.X;
  Pt.Y := Mouse.CursorPos.Y;
  //  Translate them into the coordinate system of the DBGrid
  Pt := DBGrid1.ScreenToClient(Pt);

  //  Use TDBGrids inbuilt functionality to identify the Column and
  //  row number. 
  ACol := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y).X -1;
  ARow := DBGrid1.MouseCoord(Pt.X, Pt.Y).Y;
  CellValue := DBGrid1.Columns[ACol].Field.AsString;

  Caption := Format('Col:%d Row:%d Cell Value:%s', [ACol, ARow, CellValue]);
end;
```

Note that I've used the Caption property of the form to display the grid cell info just as a quick n dirty way of showing the information somewhere.  Of course you could equally well display it on another area of the form or somewhere on a different form entirely.  The above code will work equally well in the grid's `OnCellClick` event, btw.

As noted in a comment, you can use the grid's `SelectedField` property instead of the above, but personally I think the above is more instructive of how to work with a DBGrid, because it shows how to get the cell's Column and Row coordinates.  See the DBGrid's `SelectedField`, `SelectedIndex` and `SelectedRows` properties in the Online Help for more info on useful properties of the TDBGrid.

**Update**  You asked in a comment for an example of showing the information on another form.  Let's suppose this form is called `OtherForm`, is in a unit `OtherFormu.Pas` and is created before the `DBGrid1DblClick` evenbt is called.  You need to use this unit in the Useslist of the unit which contains the DBGrid. Let's suppose this other form contains a TMemo control called Memo1.  Then, you could write your `DBGrid1DblClick` hanndler like this:

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
[as above]
begin
  [ as above ]
  CellValue := DBGrid1.Columns[ACol].Field.AsString;

  OtherForm.Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Col:%d Row:%d Cell Value:%s', [ACol, ARow, CellValue]));
end;
```

Comment: You don't need all those cell locating code, you can use the SelectedField of the grid.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz:  So?  It illustrates how to do it from scratch, which is useful to know, imo, and hints how to do it when the cell of interest isn't currently selected.

Comment: *"So?"* - Because the code is not exactly necessary. Seems to be a valid reason to comment to me.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz:  Fair enough.

Comment: @MartynA - you're amazing. You keep answering my questions and so far your answers are stellar. Truly thank you. It works perfectly. 2 problems: You mentioned it changes the caption, but I'd like instead of the caption for it to be a new TForm that display the respective data, one I can close. 2nd problem is - If i select another row after (single click, not double) the caption doesn't revert back to the previous state. The 2nd problem wouldn't be a problem If I can show that in a TForm, but I'm just mentioning it so others can know if they come here down the line and use the code as caption.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - thanks for the alternative, I'll look in to that too at least so I can learn another new thing, I'm pretty new to delphi, thank you.

Comment: @MartynA - can you provide a code example how to add the new form with TDBMemo on it to display the info there instead of the caption? I'm having difficulty modifying your example so I can do that, I'm rather new to Delphi so I'm sorry if it looks like I'm just looking for free code with no work, it's not the case. I'm hoping I learn better with concrete ready made examples. Hope it's ok! - dbgridCelulaForm is the name of the new form containing the TDBMemo, name of the memo is DBMemoCelula

Comment: I've added an example of how to add the info from the dbl-click event to a memo on another form.  I've avoided using your dbgridCelulaForm because it is totally unclear to me whether the contents of the TDBMemo on it are writeable, whether it's connected to the same dataset as your DBGrid, etc.  But you should be able to get the idea easily enough though.

Comment: @MartynA - Works flawlessly, again, my gratitude! Have a nice day :)